# Are there any ways to return to original state after click on a button?

Tags: html, css

i want after click on button the background back to the original color (blue) but after i have clicked button, it stays on the focus color (green color). is there any solution for my situation? i have tested some ways like animation but it failed. here are my codes:

```html
<button>button</button>
           
<style>
    button {
        padding: 10px 35px;
        background-color: blue;
        color: #fff;
    }
    button:focus {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The question in unclear. Once you've clicked, do you want the button to be blue or green ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `:focus` to `:active`.

```css
button {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

button:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace "button:focus" with "button:hover". This way the color of the button changes on hover (which you are doing when clicking a button). When the mouse leaves the element, the button has it's original color back. Look at the code below:

```html
  <button>Add to cart</button>

       

  <style>
          button {
              padding: 10px 35px;
              background-color: blue;
              color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;

          }
          button:hover {
                  background-color: green;
              }
      </style>
```

Comment: but i want create a shopping button, if a user add something to her/his cart by clicking on button, it's backgroung be green an then convert to it's orginlal color (blue). i hope to transfer my question properly.

Comment: That is what happens when you apply this. When a user adds something to her/his cart the button will be green. But after the click, it will be blue again. If this is not what you mean, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button")

btn.setAttribute("class", "")

btn.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  btn.classList.add("green")
})

btn.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  btn.classList.remove("green")
})

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  btn.classList.remove("green")
})
```

```css
button {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
button.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```